# $UT$ is not Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}$$^3$ into $\mathbb{R}$$^2$, and let $U$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}$$^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$$^3$. Prove that the transformation $UT$ is not invertible.

Is there any generalisation of this?

Comment: The rank of $UT$ is at most $2$, therefore its not invertible. A possible generalization is: if a linear map $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ factors through a space of dimension $k\le n$, i.e. there exists $U:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $F=U\circ T$, then the rank of $F$ is at most $k$.

Comment: @ Your Ad Here : can you prove rank$(UT)$= $2$

Comment: @Mathematics: It is actually $\leq 2$ . Look, e.g., at rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Not $=$ (e.g. $U=T=0$ gives rank $0$), but $\le$. That is clear, because $U$ has rank $\le$ 2.

Comment: @  user99680 : Please explain!

Comment: @Your Ad Here: do you want to write it or should I ? Or maybe Mathematics, you want to write it?

Comment: @Mathematics: Rank is the dimension of the image. The image of $UT$ is contained in the image of $U$, which has dimension $\mathrm{rank} U\le 2$.

Comment: @Mathematics : Please see my answer below see if you like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the rank-nullity theorem:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem:

If you have a linear map $L :V\rightarrow W$ , then the dimension of $V$ equals the sum of the rank of $L$ ( the dimension of the image)+ the nullity , equivalently the dimension of the nullspace. In our case, we have a linear map $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $ , so that $dimV=2$. Then $$ 2=Dim(ImT)+Dim(NullT) $$

From this it follows that $Dim(ImT) \leq 2$.

Now, we have a composition of maps $$T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 U: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $$

Even if the image of $T$ has rank $2$, the image $UT$ will be the image of a 2-D space so that the composed map $UT$ cannot have a three-dimensional image in $\mathbb R^3$, which is what you need for an injection into $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @ user99680 : yeah! I got it! Thank you!

Comment: @Mathematics: Excellent, good going.

Answer (score 0):

> Generalization:$V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F.$ Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ to $W,$ and let $U$ be a linear transformation from $W$ to $V$ with $\dim V >\dim W.$ Then $UT$ is not invertible.

We see that $UT$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V.$ Let $\dim V=m.$ If $\{\alpha_i \}_{i=1}^{i=m}$ is a basis for $V,$ then $UT$ is completely determined by its action on these basis vectors.

Consider $\{T(\alpha_i)\}_{i=1}^{i=m}.$ This set is clearly linearly **dependent.** Thus there exists $c_i$'s $\in F,$ not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^{i=m}c_iT(\alpha_i) =0.$ Applying $U$ on both sides we get $\sum_{i=1}^{i=m}c_iUT(\alpha_i) =0.$

The set $\{UT(\alpha_i)\}_{i=1}^{i=m}$ is not a basis for $V$ and thus $UT$ is not invertible.